# How to insert a column to make it auto increment according to another column

Tags: mysql, race-condition

There is the table:

| id | type | serial_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 1 |
| 2 | banana | 1 |
| 3 | banana | 2 |
| 4 | apple | 2 |
| 5 | water | 1 |

I want the `serial_no` to be auto increment for every `type`

I tried

```
INSERT INTO MY_TBALE
(type, serial_no)
VALUES
(
apple, 
(SELECT (COALESCE(MAX('type'), 0)+1 FROM MY_TABLE T1 WHERE type=apple)
)
```

, but it seems not working on multi-threads system.
I got some duplicate `serial_no` on same `type`.

Comment: Look at implementing a partitioned row_number in a view.

Comment: Yes, you have discovered a [race condition](https://devopedia.org/race-condition-software). You can't do what you're describing without locking the table. Only one thread at a time can have exclusive access to the table, so it can read the MAX serial_no value and insert a new row without competing with other threads.

Comment: read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html